# Handling #include paths on different platforms

Tags: c++, linux, windows, git, ncurses

I'm developing a software on an Arch Linux platform with NCurses. It has an `#include <ncurses.h>` in a global header.

My collaborator works in Windows and emulates a bash shell with Cygwin. However, cygwin installs ncurses libraries such that you have to use `#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>`. It's trivial to change, but our Git history could consist of that line changing back and forth multiple times if one of us forgot which seems silly.

Is there some kind of preprocessor check I could do to use the appropriate path?

Comment: This should be part of your makefile (or windows equivalent). So using gcc you would use the `-I` option to specify an include directory. So on one machine you might build with `-I/path/to/ncurses/include` and on the other `-I/different/ncurses/include/ncurses`, so that you can use just `#include <ncurses.h>` on both.

Comment: Note that [`pkg-config`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) is a good way to get all the necessary gcc flags, include paths, library paths, etc, and has been installed by default on every Linux distribution I've ever tried to use it on.

Comment: This is the type of problem GNU autotools are designed to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BoBTFish said, you should specify the include path in the Makefile (different for each platform). If not, you can use the macro `__CYGWIN__`  (or `__CYGWIN32__`, not sure which one will work) to detect if you're using `cygwin`, like

```
#ifdef __CYGWIN__
#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>
#else
#include <ncurses.h>
#endif
```

See http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/predefined-macros-platform.html for more details.

Comment: It's not so much the makefile, but the configuration of however you are building. You have to be configuring your build somehow (evidently as you are building). My point is that this difference should be handled at that level if possible, not in code. When you add a third platform, you add a third, `#ifdef`, ...

Comment: Right, I agree, I would also use `-I/path/to/my_ncurses` on the specific machine, was just providing the alternative in case they don't want to tweak the config files. On the other hand, sometimes you have to do this kind of checks in the `Makefile` (or config file) itself, but again I agree, the code should be kept as clean as possible.

Comment: #ifdef is evil, and hard to maintain. Fix this in the makefile/cmake/autotools/scons/..., where it belongs.